# Prove $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]/\left\langle p\right \rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/\left \langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, eisenstein-integers

> Let $\omega=e^{2\pi\over 3}$ and let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. Let $p>3$ be a prime number. Prove $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]/\left\langle p\right \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/\left \langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle$.

I have observed that $R/\left\langle p \right\rangle=\{a+b\omega: 0\leq a<p, b\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$
But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Indeed, $R/\langle p \rangle = \{a + b\omega \ | \ 0 \leq a < p, 0 \leq b < p\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we observe that since $\omega^3=1$, $\omega$ will be a root of $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.  Further, since the second factor is irreducible and $\omega \neq 1$, it satisfies $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$.

Now, we just observe that 
$$(\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle)/\langle p \rangle> \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1,p\rangle\cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle p \rangle)/ \langle x^2+x+1 \rangle$$

Comment: $(e^{(2\pi i)/3})^3=e^{3\cdot (2\pi i)/3}=e^{2\pi i}=1$. You did your math wrong.  While you have the right formula for $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ (except for a missing $i$, which is a typo), you then have a difference of squares $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, with $a=-1/2$ and $b=i\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: Suppose you have an algebraic element $\alpha$ that satisfies some minimal polynomial $f(x)$.  Then we have a map $\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z[\alpha]$ sending $x$ to $\alpha$.  This is surjective, and the kernel will be those polynomials $g$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$.  This ideal is equal to $\langle f(x) \rangle\subset \mathbb Z[x]$.  By the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \cong \mathbb Z[\alpha]$.  This is the standard construction for adjoining algebraic elements.

Comment: Can you please expand what do you mean by arguing $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle$? I don't understand the equivalence.

Comment: @J.Doe $x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\omega$, and every polynomial that $\omega$ satisfies is a multiple of this polynomial.Further details are spelled out in the other comment.

Comment: Yes, I was just repost the comment and just then read the comment above.

Comment: Thank you very much. The last piece I don't understand is why if $a$ satesfies a minimal polinomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and if $A$ is the set of all polinomyals that are setesfied by $a$, then $A\subseteq \left\langle f \right \rangle$?

Comment: @J.Doe This actually requires $f$ to be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.  Then we can divide any polynomial by $f$ to get a remainder polynomial $r$ (the division algorithm runs into issues if you try to divide by a non-monic polynomial, as you might not end up with integer coefficients otherwise).  Now, if $f(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha)=0$ and $g(x)=q(x)f(x)+r(x)$, then $r(\alpha)=0$.  But if $f(x)$ is the smallest degree polynomial that $\alpha$ satisfies (def of minimal polynomial), then since $r(x)$ has lower degree, it must be zero or we would have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the third isomorphism theorem.

First, note that

$$\mathbb{Z}[\omega]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1\rangle$$

and thus

$$\mathbb{Z}[\omega]/\langle p\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle p, x^2 + x + 1\rangle$$

which is isomorphic to

$$(\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle p \rangle)/\langle x^2 + x + 1\rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1\rangle.$$